# Spring JPA working with JSON column

Tags: json, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am wondering if there is a good example that can help me to find the proper way of working with JSON column using Spring JPA. My problem is that for historical reasons we have Jsonb columns in PostgreSQL database and creating Spring models on top of this columns are tricky or I cant find a proper example. Below you can find Model representing DB table

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Profile {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

@JsonRawValue
private String details;

@JsonRawValue
private String locations;

private String coverImage;
private String profileImage;

}
```

Is there an easy way to perform a Search query on those inner JSONs.I tried to use `@Convert` annotation, it works for Read but it fails while trying to use JPA for search queries: e.g  `repository.findByLocations(List<Location> locations)` because of its trying to compare Jsonb to varchar.

Please share your ideas

Comment: is `locations` list?

Comment: @SergiiGetman yes, Json List

Comment: if you have to find equals `IN` list use `findByLocationIdIn(List locationIds)`. you have to extracts id location

Comment: There is no ID in Location entity. But i tried `repository.findByLocationsIsIn(i.getLocations());`  and result is `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb = character varying`

Comment: See here for examples, including querying via native queries: https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/06/20/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/